# Ag-Grid Filter Comma

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

im using ag-Grid, but there is a issue when it filters my data, when i filter my data in the price column, it only works with numbers dot and not with commas.

```
Link: https://plnkr.co/edit/LDdrRbANSalvb4Iwh5mp?p=preview
```

Practical Example: 
In the Price column select box equal and above insert "1.5" and than try inserting "1,5"

Answer (score 1):

This is because this filter is a native one.

If you want to handle custom behaviour, define your own filter.

Documentation : https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-filtering/index.php

A quick and dirty solution would be to monkey patch the NumberFilter like this :

```
NumberFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (node) {
            if (this.filterNumber === null) {
                return true;
            }
            var value = this.valueGetter(node);
            if (!value && value !== 0) {
                return false;
            }
            var valueAsNumber;
            if (typeof value === 'number') {
                valueAsNumber = value;
            }
            else {
                valueAsNumber = parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'));
            }
            switch (this.filterType) {
                case EQUALS:
                    return valueAsNumber === this.filterNumber;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    return valueAsNumber < this.filterNumber;
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    return valueAsNumber > this.filterNumber;
                default:
                    // should never happen
                    console.warn('invalid filter type ' + this.filterType);
                    return false;
            }  
};
```

Then changed line is here :

```
 valueAsNumber = parseFloat(value.replace(',','.'));
```

Comment: kinda of a side question but is ag-grid widely used? I've been having some issues using it with an angular 2 app and find it really hard to get help.

Comment: IT doesnt work, i still cant filter in the price using commas, only dots numbers

Comment: @Thaenor go on the ag-grid forum if you need help. Angularjs 2 is still young but the developer is very active on the grid currently, adding features and supporting more framework to work with. The grid does integrate with angularjs2

Comment: @MarcoPereira can you check with the console debugger what happen with the value variable ? and what return value.replace(',','.') ?

Comment: @Thaenor what is happening is the value is has typeof number, so when is called replace it doesnt recongnize, because this is a method of the string, so what i did is when it was called i convert the value has a string and than replace and convert has a number, but i still cant it replace the comma by the dot, here it is code example:

http://pastebin.com/ZzsvnDEi

Comment: @MarcoPereira I've already made a post on the ag-grid foruns, but the place seems rather dead, seing as no one replied. https://ag-grid.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=3494

Comment: @Thaenor I answered you on the forum, here's is a c/c : When rowData change you have to use api.setRowData(), the list pass on gridOptions is only use at initialisation.

Comment: @MarcoPereira I just tried that but it didn't work, I did get an alert but it just said "[Object][Object]"

Comment: hello @Thaenor i found the solution, is much easyer, but the problem is i dont have idea in how to overwrite the function in the configuration file, here i leave the link of the function changed:
http://pastebin.com/LiRPmpT6

Comment: @MarcoPereira sorry I kinda threadjacked this, I don't really have the problem initially mentioned in this thread. I was curious because I was finding it really hard to get help for my problem. I wanted to get a sense if angular 2 and it's 3rd party libs were "mature enough" for development.

Comment: @Thaenor well angular 2 is just out so every 3rd party library integration in angular 2 is not really mature yet i guess

Comment: @Walfrat I guess that is true.

Answer (score 0):

So i found the problem, first i had to convert the value has a string than i needed to replace the dot by the comma, the problem with the answer above was first because of the data type and than the order of the properties of the replace function, but the problem now is that is not filtering correctly, if i search using equal option if gives me 2 values, instead a fixed one, code looks something like this:

Code:

```
NumberFilter.prototype.doesFilterPass = function (node) {

            if (this.filterNumber === null) {
                return true;
            }
            var value = this.valueGetter(node);
            if (!value && value !== 0) {
                return false;
            }
            var valueAsNumber;
            if (typeof value === 'number') {
            value = value.toString()
                valueAsNumber = parseFloat(value.replace('.',','));
            }
            else {
                valueAsNumber = parseFloat(value.replace('.',','));
            }
            switch (this.filterType) {
                case EQUALS:
                    return valueAsNumber === this.filterNumber;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    return valueAsNumber < this.filterNumber;
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    return valueAsNumber > this.filterNumber;
                default:
                    // should never happen
                    console.warn('invalid filter type ' + this.filterType);
                    return false;
            }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

NumberFilter.prototype.onFilterChanged = function () {

```
        var filterText = utils_1.default.makeNull(this.eFilterTextField.value);

        if (filterText && filterText.trim() === '') {
            filterText = null;
        }
        var newFilter;
        if (filterText !== null && filterText !== undefined) {

        console.log(filterText);

            // replace comma by dot
            newFilter = parseFloat(filterText.replace(/,/g, '.'));
            console.log(newFilter);
        }
        else {
            newFilter = null;
        }
        if (this.filterNumber !== newFilter) {
            this.filterNumber = newFilter;
            this.filterChanged();
        }
    };
```